# Exception: The mediaData parameter only supports Blob types for upload

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to export a csv from a Google sheet and give it the name entered into a dialog box. the code is:

```
var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var sheet_Name = "csv" 
 

var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet_Name)
  var sheetNameId = sheet.getSheetId().toString();

  params= ssID+"/export?gid="+sheetNameId +"&format=csv"
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ params
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData);

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Enter Name for CSV");
  var csvName = result.getResponseText();
  

  var folder_id ='1ENj9Rk0djm2jp0FOorWcWmsIEqEp1pFp';
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "YYMMdd");


  var resource = {
  title: date+csvName+".csv",
  mimeType: "application/vnd.csv",
  parents: [{ id: folder_id }]}

  var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource, result, {supportsAllDrives: true});
```

Problem is I just get:

Exception: The mediaData parameter only supports Blob types for upload.

Is this an easy fix??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, `result` of `var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData);` is overwritten by `var result = ui.prompt("Enter Name for CSV");`. I think that this is the reason of your issue. So in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var result = ui.prompt("Enter Name for CSV");
var csvName = result.getResponseText();
```

#### To:

```
var res = ui.prompt("Enter Name for CSV");
var csvName = res.getResponseText();
```